# List of Email accounts configured in my android phone

Tags: android

I am new in android so please help me is there any way to find out List of Email accounts configured in my android phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a Android 4.0(Ice Cream Sandwich) user. In order to view the accounts that you have configured goto Settings-> Accounts & sync, you will see all the accounts that you have configured to your device.

Comment: Thank you Ananth for your reply.
But I actually want to do that programmatically.
So please help me.

Comment: I got solution for that:

Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts)
{
       // Check here for the type and name to find the email records.
        
 text.append("\n\nAccount Name : "+account.name);
 text.append("\nAccount Type : "+account.type);         
}